# Changing the text color of a button on hover using the after selector class

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I am trying out some new button hover effects but I am having some problems with setting the text color of the button. The following is my code:

```css
    .color-1 {
     text-align: center;
     background: white;
    }

    .myButton { 
     cursor: pointer;
     padding:  25px 80px;
     margin: 15px 30px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight:  bold;
     outline: none; 
      position: relative;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
     transition: all 0.3s; 
     overflow: hidden;
     border-radius:  12px;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     background:  blue;
     color: white;
    }

    .myButton::after {
     background-color: white;
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
     transition: all 0.3s;
     width: 100%;
     height: 0;
     /* z-index: -1; */
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%; 
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
     -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
     -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);  
    }

    .myButton:hover,
    .myButton:active {
        color: black;
    }

    .myButton:hover::after {
     height: 260%;
     opacity: 1;
     }

    .myButton:active::after {
     height: 400%;
     opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="color-1">    
     <button class="btn myButton"><span class="test">Button 2</span></button>    
 </div>
```

However, when you hover on the button, the text color is not being set properly and I believe because I am setting the opacity attribute in '.myButton:hover::after' to 1. I have tried setting it to 0.75 for testing purposes and apparently it is being faded away.

Can someone please help me how can I set the text color of the button to black when hovering over it, without being faded away?

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Use [`z-index`](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

`z-index: -1;` to  `.myButton:hover::after` **and**

```
    .myButton:hover,
        .myButton:active {
            color: black;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
}
```

**See code:**

```css
   .color-1 {
     text-align: center;
     background: white;
    }

    .myButton { 
     cursor: pointer;
     padding:  25px 80px;
     margin: 15px 30px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight:  bold;
     outline: none; 
      position: relative;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
     transition: all 0.3s; 
     overflow: hidden;
     border-radius:  12px;
     border: 2px solid blue;
     background:  blue;
     color: white;
    }

    .myButton::after {
     background-color: white;
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
     transition: all 0.3s;
     width: 100%;
     height: 0;
     /* z-index: -1; */
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%; 
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
     -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
     -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);  
    }

    .myButton:hover,
    .myButton:active {
        color: black;
            position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    }

    .myButton:hover::after {
     height: 260%;
     opacity: 1;
      z-index: -1;
     }

    .myButton:active::after {
     height: 400%;
     opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="color-1">    
     <button class="btn myButton"><span class="test">Button 2</span></button>    
 </div>
```